# Pointer and delete in C++

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

```
void *mm(void *pTo,void*pOr,size_t s)
{
    assert((pTo)&&(pOr));
    char* pt = (char*)pTo;
    char* po = (char*)pOr;
    while(s-->0)
        *pt++ = *po++;
    return pTo;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    char *p1 = new char;
    char *p2 = "permutation";
    p1 = (char *)mm(p1,p2,4);
    printf(p1);
    //delete p1;
    return 0;
}
```

Above is my test project. How can I delete the new char memory? 
I always get "HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED error... CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer".
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Best not to even call new or delete. USe std::vector to hold a dynamically sized memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You give p1 1 new char

`char *p1 = new char;`

but you try to write 4

```
while(s-->0)
        *pt++ = *po++;
```

You're writing to memory you don't own.

Do:

`char *p1 = new char[4];`

Then delete by:

`delete[] p1;`

Comment: Since the resultant pointer is later interpreted as a string (by `printf`), it is necessary to either allocate 5 characters (one more for zero terminator) or copy only 3 characters and use the fourth for zero terminator. In any case, zero terminator is required.

Comment: And that's `delete[] p1`, not `delete p1[]`.

Answer (score 0):

you are not allocating enough bytes "at the end of" p1. Specifically you are only allocating a single byte, but copying 4 bytes to the location. Hence you write 3 bytes beyond the space allocated.

Instead allocate p1 as:

```
char *p1 = new char[4];
```